# C# implementing system-dependent integer

Tags: c#, integer

I need to define a system-dependent integer type, in order to be compatible with some low-level librarys. I've setup a x86 and x64 Project-Configuration, and defined conditional compilation symbols for them (IA32 and INTEL64).

So, I would like to do the following:

```
#if IA32
    typedef int SysInt;
    typedef uint SysUInt;
#elif INTEL64
    typedef long SysInt;
    typedef ulong SysUInt;
#endif
```

However, that doesn't work due to typedef is not available in C#. What's the best option to implement this?

Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you will have to write conditional statements wherever you declare them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr`, which are 32 bits in 32-bit processes and 64 bits in 64-bit processes. Since these types automatically take the process's "bitness", there's no need for conditional compilation or two different projects configurations in order to use them.

If you actually want to do math on the values, though, you should cast them to `long` or `ulong` to do the math and then back to `IntPtr` or `UIntPtr` to pass them to your external libraries.

Comment: +1 | If that's the only way ... I tought I can easily use a "normal" integer instead of the IntPtr types.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: What do you think the advantage would be to using a "normal" integer instead of the `IntPtr` types?

Answer (score 3):

You could try aliases:

```
#if IA32
using SysInt = System.Int32;
#elif INTEL64
using SysInt = System.Int64;
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you could do something like this, at least:

```
#if IA32
    using SysInt = System.Int32;
    using SysUInt = System.UInt32;
#elif INTEL64
    using SysInt = System.Int64;
    using SysUInt = System.UInt64;
#endif
```

This just aliases the types for you. I don't know how useful that is for your purposes, but it's something.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if IA32
public struct Sys
{
   public int Int { get; set; }
}
#elif INTEL64
public struct Sys
{
   public long Int { get; set; }
}
#endif
```

Comment: For a single int you should use a struct. And make it immutable.

Comment: Yep, was just about doing that ;)

Comment: You can't make a readonly property... You'll need a constructor for a readonly field :-)

Comment: Using a `struct` like this wouldn't work because it won't marshal correctly when he uses P/Invoke.